# What does Objective-C program's startup routine do?

Tags: objective-c

I know that information about all loaded classes is gathered at the startup time. But I could not find any information on how it is done and how is Objective-C startup routine looks compared to a plain C program's startup routine.

I'm just wondering what was added in Objective-C from this point. Is Objective-C program a C program with some additions or it is completely different by its structure?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this article from Cocoa with Love: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/cocoa-application-startup.html , which gives a good overview.

However, if you really want to know what's going on, it's going to be a bit of a dig, but you can look at the source to the runtime at http://opensource.apple.com/ .   Look for the objc4* project inside of whichever OS you are interested in.  Look to `objcrt.c` for the top of the initialization chain.

You asked two discrete questions in your original post: what the startup routine looks like (which is covered in the runtime) and "Is Objective-C program a C program with some additions".   The answer to the latter is yes, it is a C program with some additions, in the same manner as C++.   And, like C++, it contains some pretty significant additions to the runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already seen the Cocoa with Love description, it is helpful but very general. The objc4 project is the runtime implementation, I'm asking about a generated code that calls this runtime.